# I want to make photo near my text putted in square, how can center it?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the part of my site centered,there is one img and text putted in square,but also it should be responsive, here is my css and html codes:

```
#part1{
    padding-bottom:100px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:80%;
}

#part1 h1{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:250%;
    padding-top:35px;
}

#part1 p{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:110%;
    padding:30px;
    background-color:#F0F8FF;
    margin-top:60px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 60%;
    float:left;
}

#part2 h1{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:250%;
}
```

and html:

```
     <section id="part1">
         <div class="container">
             <h1>About</h1>
             <div class="about-center">
                 <p>Accommodation in comfortable guest houses made of river stone on the shore of the lake, the possibility of constant communication with animals,</br> horseback riding through endless meadows, the possibility of developing a life, ecological food from the products of one’s own farm and unity with the spirit of the village, this is agro-tourism in Zagatala.</br> Those who wish can walk to domestic cows, cook cottage cheese, mow hay and much more.</br>
Eco-farm "Lake of Hope" is, first of all, an ecologically clean, healthy and congenial holiday, which highly appreciates the level of noise and bustle of the general population.</p>
                 <img id="about-image" src="images/about.jpg" width="570" height="450" />
             </div>
         </div>
     </section>
```

Comment: so you want like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQgMj.jpg , text in left, image left

Comment: if so use CSS GRID, more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: if do text and img left, they won't be centered and responsive

Comment: I tried to do that by width:80%; but its not responsive and symmetric

Comment: yes, it will be responsive, i will write some sample and send you a answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe the site you've posted uses css `flexbox` to deal with responsive design and div alignment. You can learn about this here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

```css
.about-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This should do the trick.

To make it responsive you can use `flex-wrap` property to make the content inside the `.about-center` class wrap so that the text will be on top of the image when the width of the screen shrinks.

Comment: Thanks,i don't know about flex box (this is my first project).Maybe you know can I make them a little closer want my square be a little in my img

Comment: You can either change the justify-content property to space-around or set the padding of the .about-center container if you want them to be closer to each other and not overlap. And if you want the square to be on top of an image you can set the negative margin of a square block.

Answer (score 0):

using `CSS grid`, we don't need a lot of code, and it will also be responsive always!

**useful docs:**

- `CSS grid`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid
- `grid-template-columns`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns
- `object-fit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
- `place-items`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items

[image]

```css
.about-center {
  display: grid;
  /* 50% 50% */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* centering */
  place-items: center;
  /* 1gap between items */
  gap: 1rem;
  /* padding */
  padding: 0.5rem;
  /* for debugging purposes, delete this */
  border: 1px solid red;
}


/* responsive image */

.about-center img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* make image not stretch */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="part1">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="about-center">
        <!-- 1 -->
        <div>
          <h1>About</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Est eaque aspernatur soluta non, pariatur adipisci labore? Voluptatibus quis repellat placeat ex debitis. Quia, perspiciatis commodi tempora odio saepe praesentium beatae!</p>
        </div>

        <!-- 2 -->
        <img id="about-image" src="https://picsum.photos/500" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: it does not work, because it make my text square and img separated, one on left side and another on right side